# How to delete older files in a folder in unix?

Tags: shell, find

I need to find the meaning of the below statement:

```
find /sourcedirectory -mtime +2 -exec mv "{}" /destination/directory/ \;
```

Comment: Next time, *please* specify *which* Unix you're talking about. (Or as in this case, which *find*.) AIX is not FreeBSD is not OS X, for example.

Comment: Also, the title and the question do not match.

Answer (score 7):

It means that every file or folder under /sourcedirectory older than two days should be moved to /destination/directory/.

```
find /sourcedirectory           # finds every file/folder
-mtime +2                       # sort out files/folders older than 2 days
mv "{}" /destination/directory/ # move each result to destination folder
```